# Dynamically changing the height of a div

Tags: javascript, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Height of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428199/height-of-a-div)

Hello,

I have a DIV where I want the height to be based on the viewable area of the browser - 100px. Is there a way that I can make this happen so that the DIV height is set correctly in the first place and then adjusted if the user goes in and resizes the browser. I imagine this would involve javascript.

Thanks,

Comment: There are plenty of existing questions about this.. Maybe you could try a quick search?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172918/div-100-height-works-on-firefox-but-not-in-ie-what-to-do)

Answer (score 1):

CSS only solution:

```
.foo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    background-color: lime;
}
```

## [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/v2hMm/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a post on net [Change DIV height/width with body width/height using jQuery](http://www.phpgenious.com/2010/04/change-div-heightwidth-with-body-widthheight-using-jquery/)

```
<script language=”javascript”>

$(document).ready(function(){

var height1 = $(document).height(); // height of full document

var height2 = $(“#header”).height(); // height of header

var height_diff = height1 – height2 + “px”;

document.getElementById(‘test’).style.height = height_diff; // Set the remaining height in test DIV.

});

</script>
```

where `test` is the `div`'s id.